# Error: The edge 'entry' within the route for 'normal' is not known

Tags: omnet++, sumo

I am following http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials/Autobahn to create Autobahn tutorial. I have prepared the configuration same as instructed in the tutorial.

But getting error as attached here, while opening autobahn.sumocfg for viewing simulation result through sumo-gui. [image][image]  I am using same autobahn.rou and other files as the tutorial.

What might be the cause for this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably either missed the "rename the edges" step when creating the network or have a typo in the edge name. Please double check with netedit whether the initial short edge really has the name "entry".

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "id" to "entry" and not the "name" of the edge. It's a bit misleading in the tutorials description.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you're changing the id of an edge, and not of a junction. That's the dumb mistake I made. :)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer